# Does a YouTuber know who downloads their videos?

Tags: youtube, privacy, download

Does a YouTuber, a channel manager, know which users have seen their videos or downloaded them? Of course they may know if comments are left, but this is a voluntary way of getting out of anonymity.  But I want to know how things stand if I just download videos of him (for example with Easy tube downloader) and I am only interested in YouTube and not other platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they don't know. A simple way to verify this is to check that you can still view the video if you're using a private browser window (where you're not logged in) and/or use a VPN. The same holds for the download program (it does not even ask you to log in, or at least it shouldn't).

Comment: Thank you. The fact is, I found a channel where violent things are said and before reporting it to the YouTube moderators I decided to download the videos with Easy YouTube Downloader to possess proofs of how stupid this video maker is :-(

Comment: In fact, the downloader didn't ask me to log in. But in principle this does not prevent me that It work via the YouTube app, in which I am logged in.

Comment: However, I don't see how the fact that I can still see the video can be taken as proof that the YouTuber hasn't viewed my nickname (in YouTube I use my real name as nickname).